# Unwanted Django database sync on azure

Tags: django, sqlite, azure

I am working with azure for my Django project. The problem I am having is that my local project has an SQLite database and my azure has its own database. Every time I make any changes to my local Django project and publish it on the azure, the database is overwritten by the local Django. What should I do if I do not want my azure database to be overwritten by the local database on my computer?
By the way, I am using the SQlite database which is included in Django.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what is your deployment process to Azure? What commands do you execute to publish a new version?

Comment: I am using visual studio and I use the publish feature on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're probably pushing your local SQLite database to Azure, since it's more than likely in the same folder as your code. A SQLite database is a just a file, like any other file.

Your options are numerous, and holy dependent on how you publish:

1. If you're using FTP, just don't upload your SQLite database.
2. If you're using rsync, exclude it from the sync.
3. If you're using a git-based publish, add the SQLite database to your .gitignore file.